# Selecting html table row, grouping & counting the distinct id against another row using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML Table like this which i generated after fetching the data from the database:

```
Library Name  Student ID

New Library      1000
Old Library      1040
Old Library      1040
New Library      1005
Old Library      1020
New Library      1009
```

So far am able to count the number of distinct Student ID using jQuery very easily, here in this table which is 5. But what I want is that output the count of the Unique Student ID's belong to each Library. Such as what i want to see is:

```
New Library 3
Old Library 2
```

Is there any way to do it by using javascript/jQuery? It would be a great help.

Comment: Is there any way to put some effort you made in this question? It would be a great help to yourself. BTW, theoretically you need to group the items first (by Library name), just make a for loop and the groups should be ready. Next you can loop through all groups (each containing a list of the grouped items) and do like what you've done (which said as ***very easily***) on each sub-list. You can also count ***right while grouping***, so all we need is just 1 for loop.

Comment: I have done like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nafi_pantha/v3gh8eb3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you are getting the data from a database - I have created an array of objects - with the library type and student id. The you can iterate over that array and append each into the table. At the same time you can check if the type is new or old and also if the id is unique (by comparing it to the contents of an array of ids so that if the id is not in the array - push it into the array. Then the count is simply the length of each array.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = [
  {type: 'New', id: '1000'},
  {type: 'Old', id: '1040'},
  {type: 'Old', id: '1040'},
  {type: 'New', id: '1005'},
  {type: 'Old', id: '1020'},
  {type: 'New', id: '1009'}
];
var oldArr = [];
var newArr = [];

for(i=0;i < data.length;i++){
 $('#studentTable').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].type +' Library</td><td>' + data[i].id + '</td></tr>');
 if(data[i].type === "Old" && oldArr.indexOf(data[i].id) === -1){
  oldArr.push(data[i].id)};
 if(data[i].type === "New" &&  newArr.indexOf(data[i].id) === -1){
  newArr.push(data[i].id)};
 
  };
 
  $('#newLibraryCount').text(' Total New Library: '+ newArr.length);
  $('#oldLibraryCount').text(' Total Old Library:  '+ oldArr.length);
  $('#totalStudents').text(' Total Students:  '+ (oldArr.length + newArr.length));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="studentTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Library Name</th>
    <th>Student ID</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<p id="newLibraryCount"></p>
<p id="oldLibraryCount"></p>
<p id="totalStudents"></p>
```